# run rails app with an ubuntu server with global ip

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently, we are running our [rails](https://github.com/evercam/evercam-admin) app, on AWS but we tried to move it to `Heroku`, which didn't work at all, now We are trying to run the app on Virtual Machine on hetzner. I can run the app on local server easily, my question is that, How can we run our rails app with a specific IP and then we can access that app anywhere in the world from that ip? is that possible to do so? We are using `PUMA` for server.

Comment: You've tagged your question `vms`, but I don't see any reference to the VMS family of operating systems. Would you like to reconsider?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can access to to your site with specific IP.

In description of hetzner Virtual Server says that server have 1 specific IP. So than you deployed and run you application y can access to app with 1.1.1.1:80 or another port.

If i understand you. Also what happened with heroku?

Comment: Am I going to start my server with that IP?